# Cumulative distribution function of variable | X |

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How do I find the cumulative distribution function of the variable $Y=|X|$?

Comment: Hint:  $\{|X|\le x\}=\{-x\le X\le x\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cumulative distribution $F_Y$ of $Y$ is defined by $F_Y(y):=\mathbb{P}(Y \le y)$.

$\{Y \le y\}$ is the same event as $\{-y \le X \le y\}$.

So we have that $F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}(-y \le X \le y)$. If we know more about $X$, we can evaluate this further.